# c# Linq - Check if composite key exists in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of errors defined as the following:

```
List<Errors> test1 = new List<Errors>();

public class Errors
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int Occurrence {get; set;}
    //.....
    //.....
}
```

The errors are unique by the combination of the two fields above.

A second list keeps track of whose been assigned to the errors.

```
List<Tasks> test2 = new List<Tasks>();

public class Tasks
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int Occurrence {get; set;}
    public int EmployeeID {get; set;}
    //.....
}
```

Also made unique by the same two fields. Essentially the `tasks` are a subset of the `errors` that have been assigned to someone.

I would like to use a LINQ query (or equivalent) to determine if the composite ID from the `List<Errors>` exists in `List<Tasks>`... To be clear it must use both IDS.

I have found the below solution but have not been able to adopt it to a composite key.

```
`var test2NotInTest1 = test2.Where(t2 => !test1.Any(t1 => t2.Contains(t1)));`
```

Comment: FYI, typically classes have singular names (i.e. `Task` and `Error`) unless they are collection types. Then a collection of those types would have the plural name (as you do in your code).

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, just add a correct condition to the LINQ expression:

```
var test2NotInTest1 = listOfErrors.Where(e => !listOfTasks.Any(t => t.ID == e.Id && t.Occurrence == e.Occurrence)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to use and `&&` operator and check both properties instead of one:

```
var test2NotInTest1 = test2.Where(t2 => !test1.Any(t1 => t1.ID == t2.ID && t1.Occurance == t2.Occurance);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function for that... Except

```
var test2NotInTest1 = test1.Except(test2);
```

If you don't have it you will need to create the interface for equal -- something like this:

```
var test2NotInTest1 = test1.Except(test2, new ErrorsComparer()); 


class ErrorsComparer : IEqualityComparer<Errors>
{
    public bool Equals(Errors x, Errors y)
    {
        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
        return x.ID == y.ID && x.Occurrence == y.Occurrence;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.
    public int GetHashCode(Errors e)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(e, null)) return 0;

        int hashID = e.ID == null ? 0 : e.ID.GetHashCode();
        int hashO = e.Occurrence.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the product.
        return hashID ^ hashO;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will compare *hashcodes* and not the fields OP needs

Comment: @Fabjan you don't think there is an IEquatable for Error?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what makes you think there is... AFAIK it's just a custom class that OP has created

Comment: Well if he is doing anything with the generic lists there would be one... but I will write it.

Comment: Is there any benefit to this method over the `Where` clauses in the other answers?

Comment: @LCaraway It should be faster -- it only needs to calculate the hashes once for list1 and list2 so it should function at O(n1+n2) -- using Any you have what is a the same as a nested loop and will get O(n1*n2) (where nX is len of the two lists.)  Easy enough to test.  Saw the speed increase the last time I had to do this.  **Note, if your lists are small (< 100) use the where method)**

Comment: I am afraid this will not compile for OP case, because OP needs to compare lists of different types `Errors` and `Tasks`.

Comment: @Fabio oh if that is true then you are right fabio (it was not clear from the question there were two different types of lists) -- of course a custom compare (based on mine) could solve that easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

> For: *to determine if the composite ID from the Errors **exists** in Tasks...*

Another approach is to use [Enumerable.Join Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
var assignedErrors = 
    errors.Join(tasks,  
                error => new { Id = error.Id, Occurrence = error.Occurrence },
                task => new { Id = task.Id, Occurrence = task.Occurrence },
                (error, task) => error);
```

> For: *to determine if the composite ID from the Errors **not exists** in Tasks...*, as in your sample:
>   `var test2NotInTest1 = test2.Where(t2 => !test1.Any(t1 => t2.Contains(t1)));`

You can use HashSet to "speed up" search for already assigned errors.

```
var assignedErrors = tasks.Select(task => (task.Id, task.Occurrence)).ToHashSet();
var notAssignedErrors =
    errors.Where(error => assignedErrors.Contains((error.Id, error.Occurrence)) == false)
          .ToList();
```

Or create your own domain specific extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Errors> NotAssignedIn(
    this IEnumerable<Errors> errors, 
    IEnumerable<Tasks> tasks)
{
    var assigned = new HashSet<(int Id, int Occurrence)>();

    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        assigned.Add((task.Id, task.Occurrence));
    }

    foreach (var error in errors)
    {
        if (assigned.Contains((error.Id, error.Occurrence)) == false)
        {
            yield return error;
        }            
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var notAssignedErrors = errors.NotAssignedIn(tasks);
```

Comment: doesn't this perform an inner join.  I think he wants Except which would be a left join with the right side null.

Comment: @Hogan, _to determine if the composite ID from the List<Errors> exists in List<Tasks>_ - "exists in" should be "Join" if I understood OP correctly

Comment: Wow I totally miss read the question -- I thought he wanted an Except.  Sorry about that.

Comment: oh I see what set me wrong -- he has a `!` before the Any() call -- which means except right?  So he should remove that if he wants the inner join.

Comment: @Hogan, you are right, text and code sample are confusing, I added solutions for both cases.